# How to get my Pokemon go account back?

Tags: pokemon-go

I signed into Pokemon go on different devices using the same google account but in one of them it made me start all over so I used it for a while then we t back to my old device and used my normal account but after a few days the Google account thing asked me goalie something on my normal account and then after that I was given my other account that I used on the different device and I can't log into my normal account anymore please help I really want my normal account back!

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per GodEmperorDune's comment.

Comment: @pppery I keep wondering how all these suggested duplicates seem to have been ignored initially - do you know how this happened?

Comment: @Joachim Because they are nothing more then comments and don't inherently bring any attention. I'm using SEDE to go through "possible duplicate" comments on questions that have never been through the close vote queue and close voting them (after reviewing that the vote still makes sense)

Comment: To add a bit on why people do this: sometimes it's a moderator or gold badge holder who doesn't want to take a unilateral action. Sometimes it's a relatively new user who may not know where the flag button is. In one case it was actually me two years ago, after I flagged a question for one reason, then decided it didn't apply but couldn't flag again for a different reason. In other cases like this one I have no idea why GodEmperorDune typed out a comment instead of hitting the "close" button, and the answer is probably lost to history.

Comment: There are about 300 of these total, for what it's worth, although the vast majority of them are so old they pre-date the close vote queue and I only plan to action the more recent ones.

Comment: @pppery Thank you for the elaborate feedback. That also sounds like a gradual and communal effort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into setting in Pokemon click the poke ball in the middle of the screen then select setting, scroll to the bottom and sign out. Also the reason you have two different accounts is because you probably made one through google as well as through the pokemon, they are not the same thing. I had this same problem today when they did the update. After logging into the right account I had my character back. Therefore it is not the device, its the type of account you choose. I hope this is helpful.